# Linking against smpeg library

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to make a barebones media player with SDL and smpeg. Currently the only code I have is as follows:

```
// Header file for SDL
#include "SDL.h"

// This is the header file for the library
#include "smpeg.h"

// Link in the needed libraries
#pragma comment( lib, "sdlmain.lib")
#pragma comment( lib, "sdl.lib")
#pragma comment( lib, "smpeg.lib")

#include "SDL_Movie.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

However when I attempt to compile this code with the following command I get an error:

```
g++ sdltest.cpp `pkg-config --clflags --libs sdl2` && ./a.out
Error is: fatal error: smpeg.h: No such file or directory
```

I believe this is a linking error with smpeg's libs and I have tried the following linking commands:

```
-lSDL2_smpeg
-lSDL_smpeg
-lsmpeg
-libsmpeg
```

Please note that I have installed what I think are the correct libs with my package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install libsmpeg-dev
```

How should I be linking this differently or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Debian Stretch box `libsmpeg-dev` sticks the `smpeg.h` header in `/usr/include/smpeg/`, not `/usr/include/`.

So either pass in `-I/usr/include/smpeg/` to `g++` or switch to `#include <smpeg/smpeg.h>`.

See the [GCC C preprocessor documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) for how it searches for header files.